# Benefit of stated @import vs. compiled @import in CSS

Tags: css, compiler-construction, less

I'm using WinLESS, a LESS compiler for Windows. In `style.less`, I'm using `@import` directives to import my `768up.less` and `1030up.less`, etc.

The compiled `style.css` has the contents of `768up.less` and `1030up.less` parsed inline, for example:

## `style.less`

```
@import "normalize.less";
/* base styling here */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { @import "768up.less"; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 1030px) { @import "1030up.less"; }
```

## `style.css`

```
/* imported normalize */
html { font-size: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; } /* etc */

/* base styling */
.wrap { margin: 0; padding: 0 5px; } /* etc */

/* imported 768up */
.wrap { padding: 0 20px; }

/* imported 1030up */
.wrap { padding: 0 30px; }
```

Doesn't this defeat the purpose of the `@import` which are mixed with `@media`? I mean, the filesize of `style.css` is now the sum of all imported + compiled files.

Even if the browser won't use `1030up` because of small screen size, will it still have downloaded `style.css` in its entirety?

Isn't the compiled `style.css` supposed to contain the `@import` directives unchanged, so that `style.css` becomes more lightweight and simply instructs to browser to retrieve additional styling if the `@media` criteria is met?

Is WinLESS compiling these CSS files wrong for me?

Ideally, I'd like to see the following:

```
/* normalize */
@import "normalize.css";

/* base styling */
.wrap { margin: 0; padding: 0 5px; } /* etc */

/* progressively enhance styling to accomodate larger screens */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { @import "768up.css"; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 1030px) { @import "1030up.css"; }
```

Please, if I'm misunderstanding the whole concept of `@import`, enlighten me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducing round trips generally improves performance more than reducing sizes.

It's the same idea as using sprite sheets. Making 4 requests for 1kb is a lot worse than making 1 request for 20kb.

In this case, it can't even do the requests concurrently. It must get the first file, parse it, and only then does it realize it must go back to the server to get another file.

Also mind how gzip works. 1kb+1kb != 2kb.

If you suspect you're in a case where you'd rather keep the files split, LESS only inline includes @import if it's a .less, so try:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { @import "768up.css"; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 1030px) { @import "1030up.css"; }
```

(note the .css instead of the .less)

More details can be found by doing a control+f, search for "Importing" on http://lesscss.org/

You can enforce the import type it's doing like:

```
@import (css) "foo.bar";
@import (less) "foo.bar";
```

Comment: In respect to your answer, there is a good reason I separate the base styling from the heavier desktop styles. Is there quickhand for knowing when it is more efficient to use separate files or inlined code? For example, if my `768up.css` adds 120kb (minified) and also uses `@font-face` for 3 fonts (with a combined average of 150kb depending on browser), how would it play out? For mobiles, it downloads `style.css` in its entirety and will not use 80% of the styles.

Comment: It sure sounds like one of those situations where keeping them split is better! I updated my answer. But to determine which is faster, use Chrome's profiling tools.